# Why is it returning cannot convert to str implicitly?

Tags: python, string, int

Its a random maths question that returns an error that I didn't expect. Please help!
The error is: print('Your score was: '+int(score))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

```
import random


count=0


while count<10:
    numb1=random.randint(1,12)
    numb2=random.randint(1,12)
    ops=[' add ',' times ',' takeaway ']
    ops2=random.choice(ops)
    question=str(numb1)+''.join(ops2)+str(numb2)
    print(question)
    ans=int(input('Answer: '))
    count=count+1
score=0
if ans== numb1+numb2 or numb1-numb2 or numb1*numb2:
    score=score+1

print('Your score was: '+score)
```

Comment: maybe because Python doesn't convert ints to string implicitly?

Comment: You can't combine str and it.  print('Your score was: '+str(score))

Comment: `print('Your score was: {}'.format(score))`

Comment: Thanks! It works now that I've put str(score))

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect. One cannot add an `int` and a `str`.

```
print('Your score was: '+score)
```

Use one of the following:

```
print('Your score was:', score)
print('Your score was: '+str(score))
print('Your score was: %d'%(score))
print('Your score was: {}'.format(score))
```

Answer (score 1):

On the last line you need to convert the integer to a string

```
print('Your score was: ' + str(score))
```

Alternatively you can use a format string:

```
print('Your score was: %u' % score)
```

This is because you cannot concatenate an integer to a string directly, e.g.
`"I have " + 7 + " kittens"` – in order to do that you have to first convert the integer (in this case `7`) to a string. You can do that by using the `str()` function built into Python.